# How to add a Model Manager to a Django-Model without deleting the objects that already exist?

Tags: python, django, django-models

the question is pretty explanatory I believe. I want to add 2 new managers to a django model. However, if I add these two managers, the objects I currently have in my database are deleted. Is there any way to get around this? Or do I need to simply remake all the objects again?

Comment: Adding a manager can't possibly delete the objects already in your database. But perhaps you've redefined the default query so that those objects are no longer visible?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it. When you add a new manager, it's a class that extends from `models.Manager` so, this new class already has all the manager's default methods.

Remember you can create a custom manager by doing:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):

    ...
```

And the add to your models class

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    ...
    objects = MyManager()
```

As you can see, `MyManager` class extends from `models.Manager`. You can see docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/)